# Css margin-top not working correctly with browser

Tags: css

I've a class for text.In my windows chrome browser,it is displaying correctly but in mac chrome browser.For eg: if my name is John duash,it is displaying John in one line and dispalying duash in second line in mac chrome.

How do i fix this ?

```
.text{
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: px;
        margin-left: px;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use like :-

```
.text{
        position: absolute;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        width:100px;
        height:20px;
        background:red;
}
```

**Position Absolute** doesn't consider **margin's**

so we can use  `position` from `top:0px; left:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px;` rather than marign's

[**DEMO**](http://tinkerbin.com/t3aQRePS)

Answer (score 0):

**Your are using** `position absolute`

than used to `top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;`

**not used to** `margin-top, margin-left`

**as like this**

```
.text{
        position: absolute;
       top: px;
       left: px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The width of the span/div/whatever is not behaving by the sounds of it, you get the second line because the browser is using an auto width that is too small.